# What is Convex hull trick exactly?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was solving problems from the codeforces.ru but I couldn't solve a problem and the [editorial](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7785) said to use convex hull trick.

I tried to read this [article about convex hull trick](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull_trick) but couldn't understand it.

Can anyone tell me exactly what is convex hull trick?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a set of lines Y<sub>i</sub> = A<sub>i</sub> * X + B<sub>i</sub>, then the problem is finding the smallest Y<sub>i</sub> for given X. Naively, you could try to evaluate all Y<sub>i</sub> for this X and choose the smallest one. But if you want to evaluate a series of values for X, then you can better determine where the Y<sub>i</sub> intersect and then for each interval between the intersections determine which Y<sub>i</sub> is the smallest. Then, given an X, you choose the corresponding interval and only evaluate the Y<sub>i</sub> that is smallest on that interval.

(Visualized by the green lines here: http://wcipeg.com/wiki/File:Convex_hull_trick1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have M lines. Given any point x, M lines are in some order in terms of y(x) value. Lines order is preserved until some intersection point occurred in which order of 2 lines is always swapped.

Knowing that scan X axis and sort lines order for each intersection point to another then you get data structure which gives you lines order for each interval (from one intersection to another) in the X axis. Thats it...