# Creating a bound polygon from array of points

Tags: algorithm, gis, polygon

I have a canvas on which the user draws with a brush. I have a huge collection of points. I want to create a bound polygon (not a bound rectangle)

Would anyone point me to an existing algorithm or help me with writing the code (don't mind the programming language).

Comment: Do you need that polygon to satisfy any restrictions? (eg. Does it needs to be convex?)

Comment: @ElKamina it needs to be very fast performance wise, to be composed only from the points that were collected in the drawing phase, basically I need the algorithm to create the outline of the drawing thus creating a polygon, is that answer your question on restrictions?

Comment: This can be closed as "too broad". Questions on Stack Overflow must be about a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance and less care about the size of the polygon, then probably maintaining the min and max of all coordinates and use that to construct a bound rectangle would be the fastest way, which requires only `O(n)`.

If you care about the size or shape of the polygon, then you would probably need one of the [Convex Hull algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), which typically runs in `O(nlogn)` but produces a compact polygon.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a polygon with vertices from your input points, then you are looking for convex hull which I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834699/what-is-convex-hull-trick-exactly/17837405#17837405).